# mysql won't start on FreeBSD

Tags: mysql, freebsd

We recently picked up a client that has a site hosted on a `FreeBSD` box. The stack is `FAMP`. Things were chugging along just fine until recently `mysql` seems to have stopped running.

There is no mysql log under `/var/log/mysql.log`.

`service mysql-server status` says `mysql is not running.`

`service mysql-server start` says `Starting mysql.` but it doesn't actually start.

Where do I start to find out what happened and how to get mysql up and running again?

Comment: How familiar are you with FreeBSD?

Comment: This is literally the first instance of FreeBSD I've ever touched.

Comment: you need to locate log (and my.cnf) to see actual error why it's wouldn't start...

Comment: The problem can be replicated by installing FreeBSD 11.2 and mariadb103-server OOTB. `find / -name "my.cnf"` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The default location for the log file (which usually has a `.err` extension) is the same place as the database, which defaults to `/var/db/mysql/`.

But of course all of these can be changed in the master configuration file `my.cnf` which `mysqld` will look for in a number of locations including `/etc/`.

You may need to locate it with:

```
find / -name "my.cnf"
```

Also, check `/etc/rc.conf` as it may contain some command line parameters used when starting the service.

Comment: I'm currently downloading a 3.5 gb .err file now to examine what is going on...

Comment: You probably only need the last few dozen lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please note.  When installing MySQL or any variant that it does not give you a default "my.cnf" file.  It's called "my.cnf.sample"  So running find / -name "my.cnf" is not going to find it for you.

```
[2010][root@reaper ~ ] # find / -name "my.cnf"
/usr/local/my.cnf
[2010][root@reaper ~ ] # find / -name "my.cnf*"
/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf.sample
/usr/local/my.cnf
```

Many config files work the same way for services installed on FreeBSD.

The reason my system is returning a my.cnf file is because I had already taken the sample file, moved it to /usr/local/ and renamed it my.cnf and then made the edits I needed to.

Comment: Do you have a reason to think that is why mysql stops running?

Comment: Could be a number of things that stop it from running.  Would need to see the error log to determine what's going on.  And that information was never given.